# Conditional Expectation and Radon-Nikodyn

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, radon-nikodym

I have a question about the proof of the existence of a conditional expectation using the Radon-Nikodyn derivative.

Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_0, \mathbb{P})$ with $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$ and let $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{F}_0$.

We can define the probability measure on $\nu$ on $\mathcal{F}_0$ s.t. $\nu(A) = \int_AXd\mathbb{P}$.

Let $\mathbb{P}'$ and  $\nu'$ be the restrictions of $\mathbb{P}$ and  $\nu$ to the measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.  By Radon-Nikodyn, there exists a $\frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'}$ that is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$ and for $B \in \mathcal{F} $ we have $\nu'(B) = \int_B \frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'} d\mathbb{P}'$.

The claim is that $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}) = \frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'}$.

Therefore, we need that for $B \in \mathcal{F}$,  $\int_B \frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'} d\mathbb{P}$ = $\int_B Xd\mathbb{P}$. (This is in the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_0, \mathbb{P})$)

We know $\int_B Xd\mathbb{P}$ = $\nu(B)$.

Also, in the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}')$, we have $\int_B \frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'} d\mathbb{P}'$ = $\nu'(B) = \nu(B)$ (since $\nu'$ is a restriction).  But it must be that $\int_B \frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'} d\mathbb{P}$ = $\nu(B)$ and I do not see why that is necessarily the case.

Since $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{F}_0$, by the construction of the Lebesgue Integral (sup of the integral of simple functions less than $\frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'}$) we have:

$\int_B \frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'} d\mathbb{P} \geq \int_B \frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'} d\mathbb{P}' = \nu(B)$.

I do not understand why the reverse inequality must hold (in $\mathcal{F}_0$ we have more simple functions to work with).

Answer (score 1):

I actually think that I have it.  $\frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'}$ is measurable wrt $\mathcal{F}$.  If it is also simple then for $B \in \mathcal{F}$,  $\int_B \frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'} d\mathbb{P}'$ = $\int_B \frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'} d\mathbb{P}$ by the fact that $\mathbb{P}'$ is the restriction of $\mathbb{P}$ to $\mathcal{F}$.  Even if $\frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'}$ is not simple it can be approximated from below by simple functions in $\mathcal{F}$ (since $\frac{d\nu'}{d\mathbb{P}'}$ is a.s. positive).  The result follows by two applications of monotone convergence.